# How to add a String in the method findById in Postman?

Tags: spring-boot, postman

[I have this problem that I show you in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTC1T.png)

[How I can add a string in the request?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mKEI.png)

[This is my method in SpringBoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnABp.png)

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41IbK.png)

[I edit the question to show this important picture. This is my table and "matricula" is a String and it is my ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsde7.png)

I need help to know how I can to add a String ID in the Postman request.

Thank you. Sorry for my English level.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For path /resource/{variableName}, the *variableName* must be same as the method parameter name or same as the alias in @PathVariable("variableName").

In your case, just change the mapping to @GetMapping("/coches/{matricula}"). And you should not use "" in request path. Request with */api/coches/1234ABC* instead.